# Simple tool to test my h2c implementation

Tags: c, testing, http2

As a part of my studies, I decided to write an HTTP/2 server that is capable of simply serving static files. I have to write it in C, which I have very little experience with, so I decided to go with `h2c` (uses TCP), not `h2` (uses TLS). I need some tool to test my server, but I cannot use neither Chrome, nor Firefox, because both of them support only `h2`.

What is the easiest way to test my server? Maybe there is some `h2c` implementation for other language, like python or js (node), where I can quickly assemble a test client?

I still consider implementing `h2`, if nothing comes up, but after looking at [this OpenSSL TLS client example](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client), I am sort of scared, because it's only a simple `GET` and its size is 4 times the code I have written so far.

Comment: I think it is not obvious what `h2[c]` is..

Comment: Why you do not use `telnet` ?

Comment: @ParhamAlvani because it's a binary protocol

Comment: sorry ... I find it now ..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I assume that if one doesn't know what `h2/h2c` is, they cannot help me anyway

Comment: You might be very wrong. There are plenty of people just happy to learn. And *many* of the good answers were not known to the answerers themselves prior the questions.

Comment: I know next to nothing about h2 and h2c, but it didn't take long for me to find the HTTP/2 working group's [list of known implementations](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations).  These include several h2c-based clients.  Among then, it claims `curl` supports h2c-14.  Apparently there is also a Perl module for HTTP/2 that supports h2c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you work in C, you can use [`nghttp2`](https://nghttp2.org/) to test your `h2c` implementation.

I just tried it against a [Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty) HTTP/2 server, and this is the output:

```sh
$ nghttp -v http://localhost:8080
[  0.000] send SETTINGS frame <length=12, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
      (niv=2)
      [SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS(0x03):100]
      [SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE(0x04):65535]
[  0.000] send HEADERS frame <length=33, flags=0x05, stream_id=1>
      ; END_STREAM | END_HEADERS
      (padlen=0)
      ; Open new stream
      :authority: localhost:8080
      :method: GET
      :path: /
      :scheme: http
      accept: */*
      accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
      user-agent: nghttp2/0.6.7
[  0.104] recv SETTINGS frame <length=12, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
      (niv=2)
      [SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE(0x01):4096]
      [SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE(0x04):65535]
[  0.104] send SETTINGS frame <length=0, flags=0x01, stream_id=0>
      ; ACK
      (niv=0)
[  0.105] recv SETTINGS frame <length=0, flags=0x01, stream_id=0>
      ; ACK
      (niv=0)
[  0.121] recv (stream_id=1, noind=0) :status: 200
[  0.121] recv (stream_id=1, noind=0) server: Jetty(9.3.z-SNAPSHOT)
[  0.121] recv (stream_id=1, noind=0) date: Wed, 17 Feb 2016 19:11:17 GMT
[  0.121] recv (stream_id=1, noind=0) custom: Value
[  0.121] recv (stream_id=1, noind=0) content-type: text/plain
[  0.121] recv (stream_id=1, noind=0) content-length: 72
[  0.121] recv HEADERS frame <length=70, flags=0x04, stream_id=1>
      ; END_HEADERS
      (padlen=0)
      ; First response header
Hello from Jetty using HTTP/2.0
uri=/
date=Wed Feb 17 20:11:17 CET 2016
[  0.121] recv DATA frame <length=72, flags=0x01, stream_id=1>
      ; END_STREAM
[  0.121] send GOAWAY frame <length=8, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
      (last_stream_id=0, error_code=NO_ERROR(0x00), opaque_data(0)=[])
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Other tool to try is h2spec https://github.com/summerwind/h2spec which tests servers for conformance with the spec